# How do I craft a composter in minecraft

Tags: minecraft

I have recently attempted to make a **composter**. I wasn't able to make the **composter** because the recipe was wrong. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Please read the description of the tag "minecraft". According to this decription, your question is off-topic on Stack Overflow. It believe it belongs on [gaming.se].

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.14:
The crafting recipe of composters is 4 fences and 3 planks.

1.15 and after:
7 wood slabs placed like an “U”

Answer (score 1):

[image: here is the composter recipe...]

The composter recipe is right here, its been updated to not need fences or planks but only slabs